# Words that are used in the same contexts across different languages

Tags: morphology, words, calques

I am looking for a list of words that, albeit not being [obviously] morphologically  related, can be used in different contexts and they have the same meaning in those contexts across different languages.

For example:

There is a word `vorstellen` in German and `представлять` in Russian.
Both mean `to introduce` and `to imagine`, depending on context.

Another example:

Again, `das Glied` in German and `член` in Russian. Again, both can mean `a member` or `a penis`.

Actually, none of these examples fall exactly into the category I described as the first pair must be related, for they are constructed in the same way in both languages: `vor` = `пред` and `stellen` = `ставить`; and the second is too close of a leap from `a member` to `a limb` to `a penis`. But I hope you got the idea.

Comment: The pair of languages, German & Russian, have tons of such words since Russian heavily calqued from German, _представлять_ looks like a complete calque of the German _vorstellen_, _член_ looks like a semantic calque of the German _Glied_.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/german-stell-and-slavic-stav-languages-who-was-first/