# Are there dictionaries translating roots from one Indo-European language to another?

Tags: indo-european, dictionary, roots, morphemes, calques

Are there dictionaries translating roots from one Indo-European language (family) to another?

Such dictionaries would be helpful for translating calques like выставка, Ausstellung, and exhibition.

But the only dictionaries of Russian morphemes/roots which I could find (e.g. [this one](http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/)) don't include the PIE roots, so it is difficult to find correspondences between them and the corresponding roots/morphemes in other languages (for example, I couldn't find any such dictionary for German at all, although I imagine that they are plentiful for Latin and Greek).

Does anyone know of any references which might be useful for such problems?

Comment: Probably you want two books, which complement each other. The [American Heritage Indo-European Root dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html) ( limited to roots with reflexes in English, a surprisingly large percentage), and Buck's [_Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages_](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/D/bo3630267.html), which has everything but is not well-indexed.

Comment: Related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/german-stell-and-slavic-stav-languages-who-was-first